# Fourier series of $\cos (x) $ in $[-\pi , \pi ] $ , coefficients are giving $0$

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, I need to find the Fourier series of $f(x) = \cos (x) $ in $[- \pi , \pi ] $ but all the coefficients are giving me $0$.

First, clearly $b_n = 0 $ since $b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos(x) \sin (n x )dx  = 0 $  because it's an odd function.

Then, $a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^{\pi}_{-\pi} \cos(x) dx = 0$ , I don't think there's a detail in this integral.

But, $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^\pi_{-\pi} \cos(x) \cos (nx )dx $ seems to have a detail I'm missing. I did the following:

$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int^\pi_{-\pi} \cos(x) \cos (nx )dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \int^\pi_{0}  \bigg[ \frac{1}{2} \cos ((n+1)x) + \frac{1}{2} \cos ((n-1)x) \bigg] dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \bigg[  \frac{1}{n+1} \sin ((n+1)x) + \frac{1}{n-1} \sin ((n-1)x) \bigg]_{0}^{\pi} = 0 $

I think I'm missing some detail in $a_n$ because I don't think my procedures were wrong in $a_0 $ and $b_n$. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the Fourier _sine_ series?

Comment: Don't forget that $\cos(0) = 1$, and that doesn't become a $\sin$ when integrated.

Answer (score 3):

You did everything correctly except for $n=1$: Note that you're dividing by $n-1$ in the last equality.

Instead you'll get
$$a_1=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(x)dx=2-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2(x)dx=2-a_1$$
by integration by parts. Thus, $a_1=1$.

This is also exactly what you should expect since the cosine is already a trigonometric polynomial.

Comment: Slight clarification, it's only what you should expect since the period of $cos(x)$ is $T=2 \pi$ and the integration interval [−π,π] is a positive integer multiple of $T=2 \pi$, so only in this case is $cos(x)$ is it's own Fourier series.